# Combining multiple rows in TSQL by case number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm new to SQL (more precisely T-SQL) and I can't seem to wrap my head around this one. I'm sure there is a simple solution and I'm just not thinking of (maybe involving subqueries and/or a table pivot). But I was hoping one of you SQL whizzes could help out a clueless newb.

Basically, I need to turn this data:

```
CaseNumber|DecisionNumber|Date       |Decision
----------+--------------+-----------+--------
444       |29833         |04/05/2005 |Sell
444       |29777         |05/10/2006 |Sell
444       |29654         |08/19/2007 |Buy
468       |29230         |08/19/2006 |Sell
468       |29192         |08/19/2011 |Sell
```

Into this result:

```
CaseNumber|DecisionNumber1|Date1       |Decision1|DecisionNumber2|Date2       |Decision2|DecisionNumber3|Date3       |Decision3
----------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------+------------+---------
444       |29833          |04/05/2005  |Sell     |29777          |05/10/2006  |Sell     |29654          |08/19/2007  |Buy
468       |29230          |08/19/2006  |Sell     |29192          |08/19/2011  |Sell     |NULL           |NULL        |NULL
```

Any ideas would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are trying to do, is that you are trying to pivot more than one column at a time. This can be done with `unpivot` then `pivot`. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CaseNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CaseNumber
     ,CAST(DecisionNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS DecisionNumber
     ,CAST(Date AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [Date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNumber] ORDER BY DecisionNumber DESC) AS RN
  FROM Table1
), unpivoted
AS
(
  SELECT CaseNumber, val, col + ' ' + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
  FROM CTE 
  UNPIVOT
  (
    val
    FOR col IN(DecisionNumber, Date)
  ) AS u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted AS u
PIVOT
(
  MAX(val)
  FOR col IN([DecisionNumber 1], [Date 1], 
             [DecisionNumber 2], [Date 2],
             [DecisionNumber 3], [Date 3])
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad4b8/3)

This will give you:

```
| CaseNumber | DecisionNumber 1 |     Date 1 | DecisionNumber 2 |     Date 2 | DecisionNumber 3 |     Date 3 |
|------------|------------------|------------|------------------|------------|------------------|------------|
|        444 |            29833 | 2005-04-05 |            29777 | 2006-05-10 |            29654 | 2007-08-19 |
|        468 |            29230 | 2006-08-19 |            29192 | 2011-08-19 |           (null) |     (null) |
```

---

However, if you want to do this for any number of `decisionnumber` and `date`, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CaseNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CaseNumber
     ,CAST(DecisionNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS DecisionNumber
     ,CAST(Date AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [Date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNumber] ORDER BY DecisionNumber DESC) AS RN
  FROM Table1
), Data
AS
(
  SELECT col, MAX(RN) AS RN
  FROM
  (
    SELECT RN, col + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
    FROM CTE 
    UNPIVOT
    (
      val
      FOR col IN(DecisionNumber, Date)
    ) AS u
  ) AS t
  GROUP BY col
)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(col)
                      FROM Data
                      ORDER BY RN
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
     CAST(CaseNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CaseNumber
     ,CAST(DecisionNumber AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS DecisionNumber
     ,CAST(Date AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS [Date]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNumber] ORDER BY DecisionNumber DESC) AS RN
  FROM Table1
), unpivoted
AS
(
  SELECT CaseNumber, val, col + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS col
  FROM CTE 
  UNPIVOT
  (
    val
    FOR col IN(DecisionNumber, Date)
  ) AS u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted AS u
PIVOT
(
  MAX(val)
  FOR col IN('+ @cols + ')
) AS p;';


EXECUTE(@query);
```

- [Dynamic SQL Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad4b8/7)

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. All I had to do was re-convert my dates back to a datetime with

CASE WHEN [DATE 1] IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,[DATE 1],100) IS NOT NULL
   THEN 
      CONVERT(DATETIME,[DATE 1],100)
   ELSE [DATE 1]
   END AS [DATE 1]